# Ring homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$ such that a^2=a

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $\ f$ is a ring homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$.Prove that if $\ f(1)=a$, then $a^2=a$. Give an example to show that the converse is false.

**My progress**: Since $f$ is a ring homomorphism, I get $\ f(a)=a^2$. So all I need to show is $f(1)=f(a)$, but this is only true if $\ a=1$ or $\ f(1)=0$. But I wasn't able to prove either of them. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $f(1)=f(1\cdot 1)=f(1)f(1)$.

Comment: I'm so dumb:P Many thanks, Pedro! Is the counter-example for the converse as follows: let $a=1$, then we have $f(1)=1$, which means for $gcd(m,n)=1$ and $m$ is not a prime, exist c,d such that $m=cd$ and $gcd(n,c)=gcd(n,d)=1$. But $f(m)=f(0)=0$, while $f(c)f(d)=cd\neq 0$ mod $n$. Is this correct?

Comment: Can anyone please help verify if my counter-example above is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

One of the properties that separates a ring homomorphism from any old run-of-the-mill mapping is that ring homomorphisms are multiplicative.  That is, given a homomorphism $\phi:R \rightarrow S$ and elements $a, b \in R$, we have:

$$\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$$

Now, how can we apply this to answer your question?

Comment: I'm so dumb that I can only see the trick now:) Consider $\phi(a^4)=[\phi(a^2)]^2 = [\phi(a)]^4$. Since $\phi(a^2)=a^3$ and $\phi(a)=a^2$, we have: $a^6=a^8$, which means $a^2=a$ ($a\neq 0$ is obvious, since $\phi$ is a homomorphism, so it must map 0 to 0). Many thanks for your help, Kaj!

Comment: Careful.  $\phi$ is taking elements in $Z_m$ and mapping them to elements in $Z_n$.  If I understand correctly, $a$ is an element of $Z_n$, so I'm not sure it makes sense to talk about $\phi(a)$?

Comment: Not saying you're wrong necessarily.  Just trying to make sure we're on the same page!

Comment: I missed that:P But I think the similar solution works by considering $\phi(b^4)$ for some $b$ in $Z_m$. Using the same method as above, I get: $(b^2a)^2=(ba)^4$, which means $a^2=a$.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm still not convinced, and even though your proof is only $4$ lines, I think you're actually making it a lot harder than it needs to be.  Consider $1 \in Z_m$.  Given that $\phi(1 \cdot 1) = \phi(1)$, and also that $\phi(1) = a$, how can we apply the above to make what we want fall right out?

Comment: Why are you not convinced though? You're right, I realized that Pedro made the same observation above:P Many thanks. Can you please see if my counter-example for the 2nd part correct?